# how to add reference of c# dll to windows phone 8 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on Windows phone 8 locking system using iris. So i have to add reference of SURF library in my project but I don't know why it gives me the following error:

> A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

Can anyone tell me how to add dll to the windows phone 8 project or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know what SURF is, but does it have a version of WP8? Keep in mind that WP8 uses only a subset of the WinRT API, so things that may work in other project types might not be supported.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Right click the DLL

Step 2 : In General Tab, Click Unblock

Step 3 : Apply then OK and add the DLL again.